# Webservice Restful using @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) doesn't show the result on the navigator?

Tags: java, xml, list, web-services, rest

I want to show a result of a `Restful` web services using `jersey` and `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`.
The problem is the fact that the result doesn't show in the Web Browser even if it's shown in the console , i have the following result in console :

```
Produit Num: P3
type: Terminal
marque : Alcatel-3
modele: GT-S54683
libelle : Trend
codeTac : 876543213
genCode : 12345678901213
------------------
Produit Num: P4
type: Terminal
marque : Alcatel-4
modele: GT-S54684
libelle : Trend
codeTac : 876543214
genCode : 12345678901214
```

i save this data from an `xml` file into a `Java` `List`.
i use the following method to get my `List` of products using the `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` annotation :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Produit> getProduits() {
    return ProduitBD.getProduits();
}
```

Any ideas to resolve this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean with *navigator*?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin , Web Browser .